# In Maya, how to launch a python script in a python script

Tags: python-2.7, maya

I want to make a def that is launching the script given in the str variable :

```
def launchScript(scriptname):
    import scriptname
    reload(scriptname)
    scriptname.do()
```

so I can do :

```
launchScript(test)
```

and it would launch the *do()* def from my test script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *easy* way to do this is to make your script executable and then use `execfile` to run it: something like this:

```
# scriptfile.py

import maya.cmds as cmds
def do():
     cmds.polyCube(n='new_cube')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   do()
```

the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block will run if the file is being executed but not if it's imported as as a module.  Strictly speaking you could get by without it if you know you'll never use the file as a module.

In maya you just do

```
 execfile ("path/to/scriptFile.py")
```

and it will run `do()` automatically. Unlike importing a module you won't need to use `reload()`, everything in the file will be re-done on each `execfile()`

In general this is fine for testing but not something you'll want to do for production code -- if nothing else, you'll paying the time to read the file off of disk on every run.